# how to issue command to cmd prompt using WriteConsoleOutputCharacter() console function c++

Tags: c++, process, msdn

i want to issue commands to cmd prompt through WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(), i have tried the following code but did not respond any result just it write "Dir" at x y cord..
I don't know whether it is possible or not, if answer is not then suggest any other solution same like this. This program is a bit part of my application.

```
int main()
{
        HANDLE hStdout;

        processHandler* process = new processHandler();
        process->start("cmd.exe");

        AttachConsole(process->getPID());

        hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

        COORD coordScreen = { 0, 0 };
        DWORD cCharsWritten;
        CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;


        coordScreen.X=csbi.dwCursorPosition.X;
        coordScreen.Y=csbi.dwCursorPosition.Y;

        WriteConsoleOutputCharacter( hConsole,"dir",3,coordScreen,&cCharsWritten );
        coordScreen.X+=3;
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole,coordScreen);

        getch();

}
```

Comment: A console window can belong to any process: it doesn't necessarily belong to a command interpreter. Even for one that does, the owning process (command interpreter) is completely unaware of the console window's contents. Changing those contents doesn't affect anything. This is evidently an XY-problem: confronted with problem X you imagine a solution Y, execpt that Y doesn't work, so you ask about Y. What is the original problem X?

Comment: Writing data on a console display isn't going to issue a system command. Its literally as smart as a blank sheet of paper with a stencil and a pen. You need to call `system()` for such things (or a host of other ways on Windows.).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Thanks for reply. if this is not a solution then , how can i issue commands to a console without interacting with it directly because the console app is hidden by ShowWindow() fun and i want to issue commands to it when it is in hidden state.

Comment: it's only practical to do that when you control the way the console window is created. in that case you can run it with a pipe for standard input. but i think it's still an XY problem. e.g. you don't need a command interpreter in order to run other programs.